# How to stop the loop?

Tags: c#, loops

Hello I want to know why the loop its not stopping? and what can I do to resolve it!

Here is my code:

```
     HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
            {


                if (element.Name == "q") { element.SetAttribute("value", word); }

                if (element.Name == "go") { element.InvokeMember("click"); }


            }
        }
```

Note: the "word" in set-attribute is a random word.

Thanks.

Comment: What your element.InvokeMember("click") does?

Comment: what do you mean "not stopping"

Comment: where do you you want to break ?

Comment: Did you put any breakpoints in to see if it's getting stuck on your if statements?

Comment: I think you want `break;` when condition is meet.

Comment: When you step through this code with the debugger, what do you see happening? Is something else restarting these loops?

Comment: the InvokeMember("click")- clicks on the search button of a web page.

Comment: i did put some break points but if i do then the whole loop will stop!

Answer (score 2):

InvokeMember is probably reloading the page. Therefore the first link is returned each time in the loop (never gets to the second link)

Comment: the first "if" statement puts a random word in the search box of a page ex. bing and the second "if" its to click the button search. i want to stop the loop after x amounts of click or something like that.